# How to get the JSON of the button payloads in Rasa and display them on the User Interface

Tags: json, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

My button payloads are working fine in the command line, but on the user-interface the button is not displayed and I type the payload but it does not work. 
My question is: 
how can we first get the JSON of the button payloads and how can we show them on the interface? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: Tried this it worked on the command line, now how to run it on the interface. 
        message = '{}'.format(intent_prompt.decode('utf-8'))
        dispatcher.utter_button_message(text = message,
                                        buttons=[{'title': 'Yes',
                                                  'payload': '/{}'.format(
                                                      last_intent_name)},
                                                 {'title': 'No',
                                                     'payload':'/{}'.format(USER_INTENT_OUT_OF_SCOPE)} ])

Comment: I think this depends on your user interface. Which output channel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the [output channel](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/messaging-and-voice-channels/) which you are using with Rasa. Depending which channel you are using, the frontend has to interpret the messages and then render them correctly. You could also write a [custom channel](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/custom-connectors/), if you want to do this within Rasa.